# Real time of SVG-Animation is different from animation time set

Tags: animation, svg, raphael

I have a question about the performance of SVG animations.
When I set de duration of an animation of an rectangle which should move frome one coordinate to another, the real time the animation takes is different from the time which I set in the animation. If the system/browser is very busy the real time the animation takes increases. I am working with the SVG-Library Raphael.js. Here you can see a code sample in which I tried to illustrate the problem:

```
var paper = new Raphael("paperDiv");
var rectangle = paper.rect(200,200,30,10);
rectangle.attr({
    x: 50,
    y: 50
});

window.onload = function(){
    var d = new Date();
    var datum = d.getTime();
    rectangle.animate({x: 500, y: 50}, 1000, "linear", function(){
        d = new Date();
        alert("time the animation should take: " + 1000 + "; time the animation really takes: " + (d.getTime() - datum));
    });
}
```

Is there any way to set a real animation time?

Many thanks for your answers!

Comment: If you use SMIL or CSS animations instead they should keep proper time.

Comment: With JavaScript no because JS code runs in a single threaded environment. And all timers/event handling interaction sums to little more than specified by your animation.